# Hide menu items in Web Forms with ASP.NET Identify

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I already know how to secure specific pages or folders based on user role(s). Can you suggest me how to hide specific menu(s) based on current user roles to hide those to which it has no access? I use bootstrap menu. Both C# and vb.net solutions will be ok.

The only solution I have in mind is to wrap each single menu item in HTML with some If isinspecificrole Then *MENU ITEM HTML HERE* End If (for vb.net), but this will create pretty scattered code.

Comment: There are many approaches here. Are you dynamically gernarting your menu? As it stands your question is too broad. But the broad outline of what I would do is have an XML site map which contained attributes as to which groups have access and generate my menu from there.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I use static ones at the moment. However will be happy to learn what approaches are available for both static and dynamic menus using Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi, any ideas here?